# Is there a way to make linux CLI IO redirection persistent?

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I have multiple piped commands, like this:

```
find [options] | grep [options] | xargs grep [options]
```

Each one of them can potentially produce errors (permissions errors, spaces-in-filenames errors, etc) that I am not interested in. So, I want to redirect all errors to /dev/null. I know I can do this with `2>/dev/null`, *for each command*. Can I set IO redirection persistently? Ideally, I would just set it once, at the beginning/end of the command, and then it would affect all subsequent/preceding piped commands. Also, can IO redirection be set permanently, so that it continues to affect all commands until it is reset?

I'm using bash (I checked the man page for bash builtins and did not see the '>' and '<' characters at the top, so I assumed it was a linux thing... sorry)

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: Questions about IO redirection are shell-specific. (For example, tcsh doesn't have full-featured redirection, so you're hosed from the start.) I'm guessing you're using bash - is that correct?

Comment: @bmargulies: Really? It's not possible to write computer programs in a shell scripting language?

Comment: Given the nature of my answer below, I agree with bmarguiles and am voting to move this over to Super User. Good question, but wrong site.

Comment: @Jefromi: Of course most shells are Turing complete and you can program in them, but this question has a *user* flavor rather than a *programming* flavor. The distinction is not, of course, without its fuzzy boundaries; but we've been making it for a long time now.

Comment: I agree, its not really a programming question; I did not know about superuser.com. Can I move it, or does a moderator or something have to do that?

Comment: 4 more people with 3k rep have to vote to move it.

Comment: @user: one moderator or five users with at least 3000 rep can (and probably will) move it. And a link will be left here so that it is easy to find. Don't fret about it.

Comment: @dmckee: Fair. I know the distinction's made. I guess my one beef with it is that a lot of these things are being used by programmers to do their work. A linux user will use the shell to do a lot of the things a fancy-schmancy windows IDE user would use the IDE for - and we have IDE questions here. But I voted to move, no worries.

Comment: @user137838: Those are redirection operators rather than "builtins". See the section called "Redirection" in the Bash `man` page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using bash, or at least some sort of Bourne-like shell.

I'm also assuming that what you want to avoid is the following:

```
find ... 2>/dev/null | grep ... 2>/dev/null | xargs ... 2>/dev/null
```

i.e. repeating the `2>/dev/null` part for each segment of the pipeline.

You can do that with:

```
( find ... | grep ... | xargs ... ) 2>/dev/null
```

You can also set the redirection permanently as follows:

```
exec 2>/dev/null
```

and (assuming that STDOUT and STDERR were both pointing to the same place before), you can undo that with:

```
exec 2>&1
```

Comment: Enclosing in parentheses is exactly what I need, thanks. Using exec seems to freeze the shell, though.

Comment: Of course I'm assuming you're doing this within a script, rather than typing the commands by hand... both suggestions will work interactively as well, but the second one will have the disadvantage of making the prompt/what you type also go to /dev/null!

Comment: I see, I thought only stderr would go to /dev/null. I guess I need to learn to comprehend bash syntax better.

Comment: @user137838: The prompt is issued on `stderr`. Try `exec 2>/dev/null` (enter) then blindly type `echo hello` (enter). Now blindly type `exec 2>&1` (enter) and things should be back to normal.

Comment: Yes, as @Dennis Williamson says, the prompt (and what you type) are sent to stderr. This makes sense if you remember that the usual reason for redirection is to capture the "real" (non-error) output from a command in a file - so you can do

    `exec > outputfile`

and then type commands (`ls`, `grep` etc) and their output will be captured in the file - but you'll see any resulting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new shell with a redirected stderr, and run your pipeline in there?

Something like

```
$ bash 2>/dev/null -c "find [options] | grep [options] | xargs grep [options]"
```

It seems to work (i.e. no visible output) when I do

```
$ bash 2>/dev/null -c "echo nope 1>&2"
```

---

Of course, a side effect is that it is going to be tricky to understand what happened in the event of anything unexpected going on, but that's your business.

Comment: A subshell would obviate the induced, extra layer of quoting: `(exec 2>/dev/null; foo | bar | baz)`

Comment: @Chris, yes it would. I'm always slow and methodical about shell programming---it doesn't come naturally to me---so psmears beat us both to it.