# Redirecting stderr

Tags: shell, unix

There is something that bothers me a lot. I want to redirect stderr to lets say fd 5. So I run the following command:

```
me@/home/me>$ exec &2>5

[1]     307
```

So what I expect as result of this redirection is, that from now errors will be send to fd 5. But this is what happens:

```
me@/home/me>$ mkdir /a 5>/dev/null
mkdir: /a: [Permission denied]
```

It sill shows the error on stdout. While when I redirect 2 it shows nothing:

```
me@/home/me>$ mkdir /a 2>/dev/null
```

Can someone please explain where am I wrong?

Comment: The `exec` and the `mkdir` are independent commands in the shell. The `exec` doesn't redirect `2` to `5` for all subsequent commands (*i.e.*, it's effect isn't persistent). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821577/is-there-a-way-to-make-linux-cli-io-redirection-persistent.

Comment: You don't want to `exec 2>/some/file` in an interactive shell: bash's prompt is printed on stderr

Comment: but how do I "rename"stderr 2? If I want to name it 5, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
exec &2>5
```

This does not redirect `stderr` to file descriptor 5. It redirects it to a file named `5`.
Note that as glenn jackman mentioned in a comment, this is done in the subshell created by backgrounding `exec` only (the `&` that you used does not mean that `2` will be treated as a file descriptor. It means `exec` will be called in the background!

```
mkdir /a 5>/dev/null
```

This redirected file descriptor 5 to `/dev/null`.

You can redirect `stderr` to a file like this:

```
mkdir /a 2>some-file
```

Now look at the difference between these:

```
mkdir /a 2>&1          # redirect stderr to fd 1, which is stdout
mkdir /a 2>1           # redirect stderr to file named "1"
mkdir /a >x 2>&1       # redirect stdout to x, AND stderr to stdout, which also goes into x
mkdir /a 2>&5          # redirect stderr to fd 5, presuming there IS an open file with fd 5
```

Comment: even worse, `exec &2>5` redirects stderr to file "5" only in the subshell created by backgrounding "exec"

Comment: glenn jackman: yes,thank you for this comment. I have updated the answer!